# Razor View Page html button onclick attribute will not recognize variable in nested code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

Why is the `id` variable not recognized in context of this js function on this cshtml page:

```
    function btnDowClick(idE) {
        var id = "#Dow" + idE + " ";
        var id2 = 1;
        $(id).html("<input id='inpDow' class='form-control' onclick='' class='aDow'></input>" +
        "<button id='btnCancel' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='btnCancelOnClick(@(id2))'>Cancel</button>");
    }
    function btnCancelOnClick(id) {
        //turn <input> and <button> back into <a>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohh sorry... now i understand
try this

```
   function btnDowClick(idE) {
    var id = "#Dow" + idE + " ";
    var id2 = 1;
    $(id).html("<input id='inpDow' class='form-control' onclick='' class='aDow'></input>" +
    "<button id='btnCancel' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='btnCancelOnClick("+id+")'>Cancel</button>");
}
function btnCancelOnClick(id) {
    //turn <input> and <button> back into <a>
}
```

Comment: That was the treat!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this

```
var id = "Dow" + idE + " ";
    $("#"+id).html("<input id='inpDow' class='form-control' onclick='' class='aDow'></input>" +
    "<button id='btnCancel' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='btnCancelOnClick(@(id))'>Cancel</button>");
```

Comment: I tried with adding new variable `id2` and I still get compile error "variable not available in this context"

Comment: No sir.  I edited the Question to show what I tried.

Comment: The jquery selector variable "id" is recognized... It is the parameter of "btnCancelOnClick" that is not recognized.